# Expected output of DFF_2 if DFF_1 has hold violation

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, output, vlsi, timing-analysis

I am trying to figure out the output of flop DFF_2 when

1. If DFF_1 has hold violation. 
   My answer - DFF_2(Q) = X
2. If DFF_2 has hold violation. 
   My answer - DFF_2(Q) = X

I understand the FF's go to meta-stable when there is a hold violation causing the simulator to assume a value of 'x' on the output 'Q'. Which brings me to my answers of DFF_2(Q) being x for both cases. Assuming i am clocking out data as in the normal operations.
Is there any different behavior that i should know in this setup ? or Are my assumptions wrong ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1BW1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are we talking before or after the data is clocked?

Comment: before the data is clocked in. I am interested in value of DFF_2(Q) while we supply 4 clock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

If DFF_1 experiences a hold-time violation then the output of DFF_1 will be unknown for that clock cycle. The Q output from DFF_1 may resolve to a valid 1 or 0 but we can't determine precisely the minimum time required for that to happen. So, at the **next clock edge** the output of DFF_2 would become unknown. Note that if the input to DFF_1 **does** satisfy its setup and hold requirements at the next clock edge, then the output of DFF_1 would have a known value at the same time that DFF_2 would have an unknown value.